# Proving a ring is commutative knowing that $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $(R, +, ·)$ be a ring and $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2$. Prove that the ring is commutative. This is what I've tried:

$$(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2$$
$$x^2+xy+yx+y^2=x^2+y^2$$
$$xy+yx=0$$

And now I don't know what to do. I'm not sure if I'm on the right path or not so I need some  guidance.

EDIT: It is not specified that it is a ring with a unit.

Comment: $(x+1)^2=x^2+1$ so that $2x=0$.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but how do we know $1$ is an element of $R$?

Comment: This depends on the definition of a ring you use, but I assumed it was a ring with a unit.

Comment: No, it is not specified that it is a ring with a unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: My apologies, I just saw your comment saying that you are not assuming the ring is unital. I'll leave the answer up but I will edit in a correct solution if I come up with one.

You're just about there. You've shown that $xy=-yx$ for all $x,y$ but you want to remove the negative sign to prove commutativity. I'll do this by proving that in such a ring, $1=-1$. That means that $xy=-yx=yx$ as desired. Indeed, let's consider $(1+1)^2$. Of course, this is $4$, but by assumption it also equals $1^2+1^2=2$. Hence, $4=2$ so we subtract $3$ from both sides and conclude that $1=-1$.

Just to note, when I write these numbers, I mean their associated object in the ring $R$. That is, when I write $n\in R$ I mean the $n-$fold sum of $1_R$.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to prove that it is a ring with unit?

Comment: A ring satisfying this property need not be unital. Indeed, let $R$ be the subring (really, ideal) of $\mathbb Z/2[x]$ consisting of polynomials satisfying $f(0)=0$. This ring has no unit but the desired identity holds. Of course, this ring is commutative so perhaps there's a contradiction somewhere with a nonunital noncommutative ring with this property. Nevertheless, a ring with this property need not be unital.

Comment: Alright, but how do we know that $1$ is an element of $R$?

Comment: Well there is no way to know this, as the problem does not state that we are using unital rings. As I showed in my comment, this doesn't follow from the assumptions either. There may still be a proof for your problem without forcing the additional assumption that $R$ has a unit, but I don't know one.

Comment: Couldn't we do this by dividing $xy=-yx$ by y? Then we'd be left with $x=-x$. Of course, in the special case that $y=0$, we don't need to divide by $y$ because then $xy=-yx$ is always true.

Comment: You would need the property that there exists a multiplically invertible element in your ring.

Comment: Just an observation: $(x+(-y))^2=x^2+x(-y)+(-y)x+(-y)^2=x^2+y^2$ since $(-y)^2=(-y)(-y)=-y(-y)=-((-y)y)=y^2.$ Then $(x+y)^2=(x-y)^2$

Comment: What does it mean to divide by $y$? This does not always make sense in a ring, even for nonzero elements. How do you divide by 2 in $\mathbb Z/4$? And even if $y$ had a multiplicative inverse (which would itself imply the existence of 1), are you multiplying by $y^{-1}$ on the left or right?

Comment: True, so I guess that doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to the other answer: without unitality, the result is false.

Define a ring $R$ as follows: as a set, $R$ is the three-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$ spanned by the standard unit vectors $e_1, e_2 ,e _3$. Its addition comes from the vector space addition, and its multiplication is defined by  $$(a_1 e_1 + a_2 e_2 + a_3 e_3) \cdot (b_1 e_1 + b_2 e_2 + b_3 e_3) := (a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1) e_3, \quad \forall a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{R},$$ in other words we impose the relations $e_1 e_2 = e_3 = - e_2 e_1$ and all other products of generators are zero.

You can check that this indeed defines a ring structure: the addition forms a group since it always does in vector spaces, the multiplication is associative (since any products of three elements are equal to zero), and the distributive laws are also fine.

By definition, this product fulfils $xy = - yx$, which is equivalent to $(x + y)^2 = x^2 + y^2$ by your calculation, but it does not fulfil $xy = yx$. Hence, there are nonabelian rings where your relation holds.

Note: This structure does not come out of thin air, this is closely related to the wedge product of multilinear forms! I do not know if you are familiar with these, but luckily you do not need to be to understand this counterexample.